# Remove Duplicates based on latest date in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I got a dataset that I am loading into my sheet via power query and wish to transform the data a little bit according to my liking before loading it in.

[image]

To give a little more context, I have some ID's and I would like the older rows to be removed and the rows which have the newer date to be loaded in.

Comment: What have you tried? Off the top of my head, seems like a sortByDate+remove duplicates; or groupByID+aggregate latest date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is described at https://exceleratorbi.com.au/remove-duplicates-keep-last-record-power-query/
"Remove Duplicates and Keep the Last Record with Power Query"

In short, sort per date in a buffered table and then remove duplicate id

Another way I think would be to group by id and get MAX date but it depends of the data size